# index.html using webpack-dev-server not reload

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-hmr

When I change my `app.js` and `main.css` while `webpack-dev-server` is running, the bundle is updated.
But when i change the `index.html` the content is not refreshed; if I add a line to the HTML, the `webpack-dev-server` does not refresh anything on the page.
Here are my `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` files.
I hope you can help me.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server'); 
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); 
var chalk = require('chalk');  
var env = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV;

var host = 'localhost';
var port = '8080';

var config = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://' + host + ':' + port +'/',
    './src/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.html$/,loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
      root: __dirname,
      verbose: true,
      dry: false
    })
  ]
};

if (env === 'dev') {
  new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    contentBase: './dist/',
    stats: {colors: true},
    hot: true,
    debug: true
  }).listen(port, host, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  console.log('-------------------------');
  console.log(chalk.bold.white('Local web server runs at ') + chalk.green('http://' + host + ':' + port));
  console.log('-------------------------\n\n');
}

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-skeleton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "webpack skeleton",
  "main": "bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "WEBPACK_ENV=dev ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --inline"
  },
  "author": "Jose Roa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

My directory structure:

```
css  
  main.css
dist
  bundle.js
  bundle.js.map
  index.html
node_modules
src
  app.js
  sum.js
package.json
index.html
node_modules
webpack.config.js
```

Every file inside the `dist` directory is generated by webpack.

Answer (score 5):

add the HtmlWebpackPlugin 
link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin
add

```
// webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin =  require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to your IDE -- see [webpack dev server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

> Working with editors/IDEs supporting “safe write”... This behaviour causes file watcher to lose the track because the original file is removed. In order to prevent this issue, you have to disable “safe write” feature in your editor.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this workaround for auto reloading while developing an app. Add to your entry point ('./src/app.js'):

```
require('../index.html'); //workround to reload page on index.html changes
```

Comment: ```require('file!../index.html');``` if you've not got a loader set up for html files

Comment: No longer works